# How can I change the visited links color in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, hyperlink, visited

I use Google Chrome Browser and I find the unvisited and visited links colors are too close each other. They are very hard to distinguish, at least to me.

I tried the old approach of modifying the Custom.css configuration file in Chrome's user data folder and no change occurred.

I'm open to solutions which include javascript code or css settings which I can run/modify in the developer's window (F12), even though they are not permanent settings.

Comment: I'd like to know why has this question been downvoted? Is it not clear enough? Is it stupid or ovbious? I don't think so, there is no solution yet available, as @haslamjd states below.

Comment: Not sure, maybe it is more Superuser than SO kind of question? Anyway, there is related one on SU: see http://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome/191170

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution that works for all platforms and for all versions of Chrome.

1. Install the <s>[Stylist extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylist/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd?hl=en)</s>. 
   EDIT: [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) (that extension was no longer available, this alternative should work.)
2. Click SETTINGS in Chrome
3. Click EXTENSIONS
4. Find the Stylist extension and click OPTIONS
5. Click STYLES
6. Click ADD NEW STYLE
7. Where it says "Style Name", name the style
8. Click the ALL SITE check box
9. Where it says "Stylesheet Text", copy and paste the following:
   `A:visited { color: red ! important }`
10. Click SAVE
11. Find a page with visited link, refresh, and you'll see the new color.

You can find colors you like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp), and you can also use a color code like `rgb(255, 0, 0)` in place of `red`.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sVkgKCIxyaM)

Comment: It's unfortunate that an extension is required. Here at Alcatraz...errr...work we are unable to install extensions. I guess developers shouldn't be trusted with that sort of capability.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I can actually see what links I've visited now! What a difference that makes!

Comment: link to styllist is dead

Comment: @JvdBerg I think it's no longer available. I can't find it either. I believe this extension serves the same purpose, feel free to give it a try. Stylish: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me, very good solution:

"If you want to DIY extension:

Create or Navigate to folder 'c:\Users[local user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\User StyleSheets\'

Create or edit 'Custom.css' within 'User StyleSheets':

A:visited, A:visited *{color:orchid !important}

note: this code can also be used in @Vic Jang's answer.

Create or edit 'manifest.json':

{
    "name": "my_custom_css",
    "version": "1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "css": ["Custom.css"]
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2
}

goto URL with chrome: 'chrome://extensions'

check the 'Developer mode' box

click on 'Load unpacked extension...'

Navigate to the 'User StyleSheets' folder which contains the 'Custom.css' & 'manifest.json'

check the 'Enabled' box next to the 'my_custom_css' extension you created

restart chrome"

Comment: When I use 'Load Unpacked' and navigate to this folder I get the 'Failed to load extension' error with the error message reading "Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid scheme. Could not load manifest." Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

### Try [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha/related?hl=en) instead.

For 2022, `Stylish` extension from Vic Jang's answer is becoming harder to configure, it requires you to sign up to deploy your own simple CSS style. BAD!

1. Install [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha/related?hl=en) extension
2. Access extension option menu

[image]

3. Go to style page, add new one and fill it like this:

URL matching: `*`
CSS: `A:visited { color: red ! important }`

[image]
[image]

4. Done, refresh your page once and you should get nice red visited link

[image]

5. If red is bad for readability on some site, add more override style rule for that URL/Site to another color.

Comment: This extension is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

visit color Links below is the link
[color links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/color-links/hiponeioelghhaljfflaaflpccedbdem)

to set color for visited page in chrome.
Add it to chrome
extension is added then open website you wanted to add
then click on extension top right corner
it shows color links click on it select color as you wish.
your wish color not there then click on # then add color code and save
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

As of version 33 of chrome browser, the stylesheets are not available anymore. So your solution on your Windows 7 pathway to custom.css is invalid.

Meanwhile, I have not been able to find a solution for this oversight by Google for those of us with visual issues.

Comment: I feel your pain.  The Stylish chrome extension works quite well to make up for Google's lack of customization.  For years I had to keep asking people around me if a link was visited and even they had a hard time sometimes depending on the monitor.  I found a nice Stylish theme for google.com, but it was still hard tell the difference so I looked through the stylesheet and replaced the visited link hex color code with a nice bright color!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DIY extension:

1. Create or Navigate to folder 'c:\Users[local user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default\User StyleSheets\'
2. Create or edit 'Custom.css' within 'User StyleSheets':

   `A:visited, A:visited *{color:orchid !important}`

   note: this code can also be used in @Vic Jang's answer.
3. Create or edit 'manifest.json':

   `{
       "name": "my_custom_css",
       "version": "1",
       "content_scripts": [{
           "matches": ["*://*/*"],
           "css": ["Custom.css"]
       }],
       "manifest_version": 2
   }`
4. goto URL with chrome: 'chrome://extensions'
5. check the 'Developer mode' box
6. click on 'Load unpacked extension...'
7. Navigate to the 'User StyleSheets' folder which contains the 'Custom.css' & 'manifest.json'
8. check the 'Enabled' box next to the 'my_custom_css' extension you created
9. restart chrome

Comment: This works like a charm! +1. However, this goes beyond just the Google results page and colors any link that I've already visited (e.g. [1] 'Home' link in the left sidebar of SO, [2] My Inbox Messages / Achievements icon links within SO beside my profile frame). Please see [this](https://imgur.com/aJ1AFu7). Any help in restricting this to work on Google search results page alone?

Comment: Thanks for the update :) However, this seems to work only device-specific.

Comment: If you want, to restrict the colors, to work, on Google search results page alone, then replace code within 'manifest.json' file: `"matches": ["*://*/*"],` with: `"matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],`, then click reload button, next to the enable/disable flip-switch, on 'chrome://extensions' menu.

Comment: Is this DIY extension portable? Because I see the Custom.css and manifest.json file has to be created in each computer that I use.

Comment: I don't think it is 'portable', unless you published it privately ,and sync your settings, with your Google account: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278

Answer (score -1):

Found solution windows 7 and 10 Tested... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylist/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd/related?hl=en

If you dont want to click the link here's how to do it

Randolph Knackstedt said:
Someone just informed me about the Chrome extension, Stylist, which I highly recommend!
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylist/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd/related?hl=en

This extension allows the user to select a custom visited link color and acts just as the custom.css did before the most recent Chrome update. Yay!

After the extension is installed, do the following:

--- click SETTINGS
--- click EXTENSIONS
--- find the stylist extension and click OPTIONS
--- click STYLES
--- click ADD NEW STYLE
--- copy & paste the following:
A:visited { color: red ! important }
--- name the style
--- click the ALL SITE check box
--- click SAVE

Now you have red visited links. You can pick a different color if you like.

Comment: I am unable to access either of these links, I get "This site can’t provide a secure connection"